# How to download all jars for an old Spring version (3.0.7)

Tags: spring

I am performing a server upgrade for some pretty old portlets developed with Spring. Developers no longer in the team used Spring version 3.0RC1 and I want to upgrade those Spring framework jars to last 3.0 version (I believe it is 3.0.7) but I cannot find any "previous versions" repository anywhere.

In Spring official site the oldest available is 3.1.4 but as quite a lot of code is developed for 3.0RC1 I don't find a good idea to do a major/minor version change.
Are older jars available anywhere? I've dedicated some time googling and can't find them anywhere.

http://grepcode.com has some of the files but not all. Files in the project are:

```
org.springframework.asm-3.0.0.RC1.jar
org.springframework.beans-3.0.0.RC1.jar
org.springframework.context-3.0.0.RC1.jar
org.springframework.context.support-3.0.0.RC1.jar
org.springframework.core-3.0.0.RC1.jar
org.springframework.expression-3.0.0.RC1.jar
org.springframework.web-3.0.0.RC1.jar
org.springframework.web.portlet-3.0.0.RC1.jar
org.springframework.web.servlet-3.0.0.RC1.jar
spring-aop-1.2.6.jar
spring-jdbc-2.5.4.jar
spring-tx-2.5.4.jar
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Spring makes its releases available in Maven central: http://search.maven.org/#browse|528292745